# How to draw five pentagons from another pentagon?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I can to draw a pentagon:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}           

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.2]
\draw[ultra thick] 
    (1,0)--(0.30,0.95)
    (0.30,0.95)--(-0.80,0.58) 
    (-0.80,0.58)--(-0.80,-0.58)
    (-0.80,-0.58)--(0.30,-0.95)
    (0.30,-0.95)--(1,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

but I want to draw the following figure:

[image: wanted]

Comment: Aren't you trying to make a paperfolding thingy? If yes, there is a TikZ library for that called `folding`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `regular polygon` from the `shapes.geometric` library. The idea is to first draw an invisible pentagon, and then draw five other, each (appropriately rotated) anchored at one side of the invisible pentagon.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.2]
  \tikzset{pntgn/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5,draw,very thick,minimum size=2cm,anchor=south}}
  \node(n)[pntgn,draw=none,outer sep=0pt]{};
  \foreach\deg[count=\x] in{36,108,...,324}{\node[pntgn,rotate=\deg,at=(n.side \x)]{A};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Kevin C - Why, if instead of Pentagon, I want a Hexagon, changing sides = 6 and deg 30.60, and. .. .360 doesn't work?

Comment: @benedito: Your `\foreach` list should be `{0,60,...,300}` instead, because `side 1` corresponds to `rotation=0`, `side 2` to `rotation=60`, ... and `side 6` to `rotation=300`.

Comment: Kevin C - Perfect. It Worked!

Answer (score 13):

A MetaPost solution that generalizes this kind of picture to any regular polygons. I have integrated the MetaPost code in a LuaLaTeX program, for convenience. The number of sides is given by the `n` parameter which is of course supposed to be an integer value greater than 2.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
  beginfig(1);
    u = 3cm; n = 5; angl = 360/n;
    % The regular polygon at the center
    z0 = u*dir(-90 - .5angl);
    path polygon; 
    polygon = z0 for i = 1 upto n-1: hide(z[i] = z[i-1] rotated angl) -- z[i] endfor -- cycle;
    % Drawing the other polygons
    for i = 0 upto n-1: draw polygon rotatedaround (z[i], 180-angl); endfor;
  endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Result with n = 3:

[image]

n = 4:

[image]

n = 5:

[image]

n = 6:

[image]

Beyond n=6, the polygons overdraw themselves and it becomes ugly!

**Edit** I've written too fast. For example, if you take n = 12 as in the following example, the result seems pleasant (to me at least)… and anyway there is more in these pictures than meets the eye and much more than I know. See Ethan Bolker's comment below!

[image]

Comment: It's too bad it becomes ugly, because it is a picture of a piece of the {7,7} tiling of the hyperbolic plane: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_tilings_in_hyperbolic_plane

Comment: @Ethan Bolker Since I don't know anything about tilings and hyperbolic plane, I'm surely no good judge on that matter. :-) I tried it for more values, and some of them gives indeed nice-looking results (to my point of view). See my last edit.

Answer (score 5):

A PSTricks solution using the [`pst-poly`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-poly) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-poly}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2.45,-2.6)(2.45,2.1) % size of the boundry box found manually
  \multido{\i = 270+72}{5}{\rput{36}(!1 36 cos mul dup add \i\space PtoC){\PstPentagon}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]